# What is the underscore function?

Tags: javascript

I found a simple github project in js and it has a _ variable. The variable is undefined and it acts as an array and a function.

https://github.com/fletom/osrs-lightbox-solver/blob/master/main.js

Where was it defined?

Comment: It's a JavaScript utility library called [Lodash](https://lodash.com/).

Comment: https://lodash.com - in this case its defined on the global window object in index.html

Answer (score 3):

See https://github.com/fletom/osrs-lightbox-solver/blob/master/index.html

It's pulling in Lodash:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.13.1/lodash.min.js'></script>
```